# Thread safe way of reading a value from a dictionary that may or may not exist

Tags: c#, dictionary, thread-safety, locking

So, I've been spoiled by ConcurrentDictionary and it's awesome `TryGetValue` method. However, I'm constrained to using only regular Dictionary because this is in a portable class library targeting phone and other platforms. I'm trying to write a very limited subset of a Dictionary and exposing it in a thread-safe manner.

I basically need something like [`GetOrAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378674.aspx) from ConcurrentDictionary. Right now, I have this implemented like:

```
        lock (lockdictionary)
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                value = new foo();
                dictionary[name] = value;
            }
            value = dictionary[name];
        }
```

Is this basically as good as I can get it? I think locking is only *really* required if the key doesn't exist and it gets added, however, there is no good "get value if it exists, return null otherwise" method. If I were to leave out the ContainsKey bit, when the key didn't exist I'd get an exception because the key doesn't exist.

Is there anyway I could get this to a more lean version? Or is this just the best a regular dictionary can do?

Comment: What's your criteria for "good"?  Fast, least amount of code, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locking is required **even for reading** in the presence of concurrent writers. So yes, this is as good as it gets if you mutate the dictionary.

You can of course always create a **copy** of the entire dictionary each time something is written. That way readers might see an out-of-date version but they can safely read.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.  For example:

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

//..

public string GetOrAdd(string name)
{
    locker.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
    try
    {
        if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            locker.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                dictionary[name] = new foo();
            }
            finally
            {
            locker.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
        value = dictionary[name];
    }
    finally
    {
        locker.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as good as it gets.

Locking is required because dictionary makes no guarantees that you can update and read in parallel at all. Even single call to get element running at the same time as update on other thread may fail due to changes to internal data strucures.

Note that the behavior is explicitly covered in Thread Safety section of [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is just fine. Note, that lock implementation has neglictable performance penalty in case of **uncontended** access. However, in order to achieve true thread-safety you must use lock with EVERY operation with dictionary - I suggest to write wrapper class, like `SynchronizedDictinory` to keep sync logic in one place

Comment: Well, this basically is an extremely specific wrapper around dictionary, so I don't think I'll need a full wrapper class. Also, the dictionary is kept private and all that as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double-check pattern, as follows:

```
if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
{
    lock (lockdictionary)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            value = new foo();
            dictionary[name] = value;
        }
        value = dictionary[name];
    }
}
```

This ensures you only lock if you actually need to, but also ensures once you *have* locked that you still need to add the value.  The performance should be better than always locking.  But don't take my word for it.  Run a test!

Comment: Note that is code is ok only in very specific case - I'd avoid it unless there is very strict control on code usage and thread management: You can't use `dictionary.ContainsKey` without locking first... unless if it is called on the only thread that allowed to do modifications to the dictionary. Note that all other threads still need to lock on read.

Comment: yeah, this is unwise - better to use `ReaderWriterLock` for this pattern.

Comment: Good to know... I have the same problem with being spoiled by the thread-safe collections - I nearly replied to OP with "Use a Concurrent Dictionary" until I actually read his post.

Comment: Good note, but because writes can occur concurrently as well this isn't the solution to my problem, though I thought it was